# Changing the colour of the particular select drop-down

Tags: css

I've created a select drop-down which takes the colour of the background(white). I want to change it to grey. This is how I've tried:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="tax_toggle" style="background-color: #E0E0E0;" name="tax_toggle" style="min-width:160px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <option value="" id="select" style="background-color: #E0E0E0;" selected="selected">--- Tax ---</option>
</select>
```

But, there is no change. What should I do?

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/dXdq6/356/

Answer (score 1):

if you want set select background-color,you should set select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="tax_toggle" style="background-color:#E0E0E0;"></select>
```

if you mean set option backgroud,you should like this in css:

```
option{
background-color:#fff;
}
option:not(:checked) { 
    background-color: #E0E0E0; 
}
```